# Highcharts : Showing wrong color in data series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I created the graph using Highcharts API. The graph is drawn correctly and showing right colors on browser.
However, when I publish my website  using  Front Face software on the TV, it shows wrong color as shown in following images.
[Link to Forum for Images](http://forum.highcharts.com/topic31779/)

The code to generate this graph is as follows:

```
var seriesData = addSeriesData(response); 
console.log("XAxiz " +JSON.stringify(seriesData));
var maxY;
if(response)
var jobsLength = response.length;
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    global: {
        useUTC: false,
    },
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'testJobTrends',
        type: 'spline',
        height :  400,

        events : {
            load: function () {
                var i = 0;
                var chart = this;
                var timeIntervalJobTrends = 2000;
                var timeIntervalJobTrends = 15000 / (chart.series.length );
                console.log("Time Interval --> "+timeIntervalJobTrends + "  length  "+chart.series.length)
                if(isYMaxRequired(response)) {
                    //console.log(response[i].displayName + " Adjusted Max");
                    chart.yAxis[0].update({max:Date.UTC(1970,01,03)});
                    if(response[0].jobName=="C_PP_DW_PROMPT_MAIN"){
                        console.log(" Product Legacy ate my head");
                        chart.yAxis[0].update({max:Date.UTC(1970,01,03,07,0,0)});
                    }
                }

                function highlightDataPeriodically(){
                    var data2 = bindPointDataColorXLabelAlgo3(response[i].endTimeUTC, response[i].pointColor,response[i].xAxisUTC);
                        console.log("After color Change  "+ JSON.stringify(data2));

                chart.series[i].update({color: '#ecb631',
                    lineWidth:5,

                    data: data2,
                    showInLegend :true,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                       // linewidth:6
                    },
                    showInLegend : true




                }, true, false);

                console.log(" y Axis Length "+ chart.yAxis.length+"  year "+response[i].slaTimeArray[0] + " Time "+ response[i].slaTimeArray[3]);

                chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('sla-plot-line');
                chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                  value:Date.UTC(response[i].slaTimeArray[0],response[i].slaTimeArray[1],response[i].slaTimeArray[2],response[i].slaTimeArray[3],response[i].slaTimeArray[4],response[i].slaTimeArray[5]),
                  color : '#614126',
                  width : 3,
                 dashStyle: 'ShortDashDot',
                  id : 'sla-plot-line',
                  label: {
                      text : 'SLA TIME' ,
                     style: {
                         color: '#614126',
                         fontWeight: 'bold'
                     }


                  }
              }) ;
                //var timeIntervalJobTrends = 15000 / chart.series.length;
                var data1 = bindPointDataColorXLabelAlgo2(response[i].endTimeUTC, response[i].pointColor,response[i].xAxisUTC);
                //if(i != 0 ) {
                if(chart.series.length > 1 ) {
                    chart.series[((i + chart.series.length -1) % chart.series.length)].update({color: '#99999a',
                        lineWidth:1,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            //fillColor : 'rgb(156,156,156)',
                            radius: 2,
                           // linewidth:6
                        },
                        //data: data1
                        showInLegend :false


                    }, true, false);
                    //chart.series[i-1].options.showInLegend = false;
                //  chart.series[i-1].legendItem = null;
                    //  chart.legend.destroyItem(chart.series[i-1]);
                      //  chart.legend.render();
                }
                    i++;
                    if(i == chart.series.length ){

                        i = 0;
                        //clearInterval(setIntervalJobTrendID);
                        console.log(" CLeared");
                    }
                    //console.log(chart.series.name);
                }

                if(setIntervalJobTrendID){
                    console.log("Set Interval of Job Trends    --> "+i);
                    clearInterval(setIntervalJobTrendID);
                    //i = 0;
                }

                 setIntervalJobTrendID = setInterval(highlightDataPeriodically,timeIntervalJobTrends);
                highlightDataPeriodically();



            },


        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "SLA Adherence : Daily",
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Verdana',
            color: '#003087',
            fontSize: '20px',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: null,
    },

    xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         tickInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        //categories: parameters,
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%m/%e}' ,

            // formatter: function() {
         //        if(this.color === '#123456') {
         //            return '';    
         //        } 
         //    },


            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                color: '#000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '13px',
            },
            rotation: -45

        },
      //  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
        //    month: '%b %e',
           // year: '%Y'
        //}

    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',

        //tickInterval: 7200000,
    //  min: getCurrentUTCDate(),
    //  max: getMaxYTim(),
       // max: Date.UTC(1970,01, 03,7,0,0),
        plotLines: [{
          //  value: response[i].slaTime,
            width: 3,
            color: '#805e36',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            zIndex: 1,
            label: {
                text: 'SLA 09:00AM',
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }, {
          //  value: currentSoftSLAPlotLine(),
            width: 3,
            color: '#b4854e',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            zIndex: 1,
            label: {
                text: 'Soft SLA 08:00AM',
                align: 'right',
                y: 16,
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'

                }
            }
        }],
        //max: getMaximumUTCDate(),
         //tickInterval : 24 * 36 * 1000,
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);

            },
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                color: '#000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '13px'
            }
        },
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                y: -10,
                backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.y);
                },
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'

                }
            },
        },
        /*
        series: {
            marker: {
                fillColor: null,
                lineWidth: 5,
                lineColor: null
                    // inherit from series
            }
        }
        */
    },
    tooltip: {
        style:{
            padding : 0,
            fontWeight: 'bold',

        },
        crosshairs: true,
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<span style="background-color:'+ this.point.pointColor+';color:#eee">'+ this.series.name+'<br/>'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%b/%e', this.x) + ' @ ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.y)  + '</span>';
        },
        useHTML: true,
    },
    legend: {
        //enabled: true,
        symbolWidth: 50,
        itemStyle: {
            fontSize:'17px',
            font: '17pt  Verdana, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
         },



    },

    series : seriesData
});
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: How we can replicate this issue?

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. Front Face is based on Awesomium 1.6.5 browser engine which does not support many HTML5 features. When highcharts draws spline, it adds tracker around spline graph which adds  alpha gradient. Awesomium 1.6.5 does not recognizes alpha gradient, hence shows it as black. On disabling enableMouseTracker in highcharts, it worked. Wherever alpha gradient was present, FrontFace didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Front Face is based on Awesomium 1.6.5 browser engine which does not support many HTML5 features. When highcharts draws spline, it adds tracker around spline graph which adds alpha gradient. Awesomium 1.6.5 does not recognizes alpha gradient, hence shows it as black. On disabling enableMouseTracker in highcharts, it worked. Wherever alpha gradient was present, FrontFace didn't recognize it.

```
plotOptions: {

            series: {
                enableMouseTracking: false
            },
}
```

Adding above code while drawing chart solved it.

Comment: Great! Thanks, this solved my issue, but in my case i need to show a tooltip on mouse hover, So i did enableMouseTracking: true